# How to set the default config for Mongoid in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have set the following config for Mongoid. 
**mongoid.yml**

```
defaults: &defaults
  clients:
    default:
      hosts:
        - <%= ENV.fetch("MONGO_DATABASE_HOST", "localhost") %>:<%= ENV.fetch("MONGO_DATABASE_PORT", "27017").to_i %>
      options:
        user: <%= ENV.fetch("MONGO_DATABASE_USERNAME", "mongo") %>
        password: <%= ENV.fetch("MONGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD", "mongo") %>
        max_pool_size: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS", "5").to_i %>
        

development:
  <<: *defaults
  clients:
    default:
      database: <%= ENV.fetch("DEVELOPMENT_DB_NAME", "development_db") %>

test:
  <<: *defaults
  clients:
    default:
      database: <%= ENV.fetch("TEST_DB_NAME", "test_db") %>
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1

production:
  <<: *defaults
  clients:
    default:
      database: <%= ENV.fetch("PRODUCTION_DATABASE_NAME", "production_db") %>
```

When I run `rails console`, get the following error.

> There is a configuration error with the current mongoid.yml.
> message:
> No hosts provided for client configuration: :default.
> summary:
> Each client configuration must provide hosts so Mongoid knows where the database server is located. What was provided was: {"database"=>"development_db"}.
> resolution:
> If configuring via a mongoid.yml, ensure that within your :default section a :hosts value for the client hosts is defined.

I think it is for overwriting `default` in the development environment. 
**Can I set the default config?**

Comment: If this is a modern Rails app you could greatly simplify and improve this by config by using per-environment credentials.  You could configure the database name in one single place in the YAML file with `database: Rails.application.credentials.mongodb.fetch(:database, "#{Rails.env}_db")`. https://web-crunch.com/posts/the-complete-guide-to-ruby-on-rails-encrypted-credentials